# In Chow's "beginner's guide to forcing", why is $\bigcup U$ a function?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm reading Timothy Chow's [A beginner's guide to forcing](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1320) (in a quest to finally familiarize myself with "boolean-valued model" forcing), and this passage on page 13 threw me for a loop:

> ... let $P$ be the partially ordered set of all *finite partial functions* from $\aleph_0^M\times \aleph_2^M$ into $2$, partially ordered by *reverse inclusion*. (...) There is a standard method, which we shall not go into here, of *completing* an arbitrary partially ordered set to a complete Boolean algebra; we take the completion of $P$ in $M$ to be our Boolean algebra $\mathbb B$. Now take an $M$-generic ultrafilter $U$, which exists because $M$ is countable. **If we blur the distinction between $P$ and its completion $\mathbb B$ for a moment,** then we claim that $F:=\bigcup U$ is a partial function from $\aleph_0^M\times \aleph_2^M$ to $2$. To check this, we just need to check that any two elements $x$ and $y$ of $U$ are consistent with each other where they are both defined, but this is easy: Since $U$ is an ultrafilter, $x$ and $y$ have a common lower bound $z$ in $U$, and both $x$ and $y$ are consistent with $z$.

The bolded part (my bolding!) looks quite dodgy to me. I assume we're really supposed to take $\bigcup(U\cap P)$, but even so the subsequent argument doesn't seem to make sense. For all I know, even if $x$ and $y$ are in $U\cap P$, their meet $z$ might lie in $\mathbb B\setminus P$, in which case it is *not* a partial function (but probably something like an equivalence class of sets of functions under some appropriate relation, given how "completion" usually goes). So why would its existence imply that $x$ and $y$ are consistent?

What am I missing here? Is it somehow an obvious consequence of $U$ being an ultrafilter? But that concept is defined only with reference to $\mathbb B$, and doesn't even know which of the elements of $\mathbb B$ were in $P$ to begin with.

Comment: The completion satisfies that incompatible things in $P$ are incompatible in the completion, where incompatibility means that $x,y$ have no common lower bound (or, in the completion, that their meet is 0).

Comment: $P$ is dense in $\mathbb{B}$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, it sure would have been nice of Chow to say so explicitly. Do you know of a good reference for this? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Boolean_algebra) speaks only of completions of Boolean algebras, not of arbitrary posets.

Comment: Henning, given a partial order we can define it's separative quotient (where $q\Vdash\check p\in\dot G$ if and only if $q$ is stronger than $p$), and we can now prove that every separative partial order is dense in a complete Boolean algebra (its regular open sets).

Comment: In general, Jech takes the approach to forcing with Boolean algebras, you can try in one of his books.

Comment: I would suggest Kunen's book. He carefully covers forcing equivalence, completions, and related matters. His approach is via posets, while Jech's is via boolean algebras. I think they complement each other nicely.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: I have Kunen's book, but here I wanted specifically the Boolean-algebra way, which I had seen praised as more intuitive.

Comment: Ah, there it is! Kunen chapter II lemma 3.3,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete Boolean algebra $\mathbb{B}$ is constructed so that this is not an issue.  Specifically, $\mathbb{B}$ has the property that $P$ is dense in $\mathbb{B}$.  So if $z\in U$, then there is some $w\in U\cap P$ such that $w\leq z$ by genericity, since the set of such $w$ is dense below $z$.

The explicit construction of $\mathbb{B}$ is this: an element of $\mathbb{B}$ is a downward-closed subset $b\subseteq P$ such that if $p\in P$ and $b$ is dense below $p$, then $p\in b$; we embed $P$ into $\mathbb{B}$ by mapping $p$ to $\{q:q\leq p\}$ (or more generally, the least element of $\mathbb{B}$ which contains $\{q:q\leq p\}$, if $\{q:q\leq p\}$ is not an element of $\mathbb{B}$, though that does not happen for the specific poset $P$ that Chow is discussing).  Each $b\in\mathbb{B}$ is the join of its elements (considered as elements of $\mathbb{B}$ via the embedding), so $P$ is dense in $\mathbb{B}$.  (Beware that for an arbitrary poset $P$ this "embedding" may not be injective, or may only weakly preserve the order.  A poset $P$ is called *separative* if this "embedding" really is an embedding of posets, or equivalently if $\{q:q\leq p\}$ is an element of $\mathbb{B}$ for all $p\in P$.)

Comment: If the construction you describe is not for an arbitrary poset, then what is it for?

Comment: It's for the specific $P$ that Chow is discussing, or more generally any separative poset.  I've clarified that point.

Comment: Would it be reasonable, then, to say that Chow oversells his point when he writes "an arbitrary partially ordered set"?

Comment: The completion still "works" for the purposes of forcing if $P$ is not separative; the natural map from $P$ to the completion is just not an embedding, and some of the arguments are slightly more complicated.

Comment: @Henning: Think about it from a preorder point of view, of course mapping a preorder to a Boolean completion requires going through the partial order quotient first. Similarly, we need to go through the separative quotient as well in this case.